# Is it possible to have a generic field in django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design, django-orm

I am currently trying to work on designing a DB schema for a chat application.

And I am having some confusion pertaining to the field type in which I should store the content of each message.

Here is the partially completed DB schema of a chat message:

```py
...
...
...


# types of chat messages available
TEXT = 'text'
IMAGE = 'image'
...


MESSAGE_TYPE = [
    (TEXT, _('Chat message type : Text')),
    (IMAGE, _('Chat message type : Image')),
    ....
]

# User class represents a user of the application

class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    """
    Class for storing chat messages between `Users`
    """

    # type of the message
    message_type = models.CharField(choices=MESSAGE_TYPE, max_length=50, null=False)

    # user who created the text message
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    # user who is supposed to receive the message
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='recipient', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    # timestamp at which the message was created
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    # whether the recipient has seen the message
    seen = models.BooleanField()

    # content of the chat message
    content = .....
```

I am planning to use encoder/decoder utilities to interpret the `content` for different types of chat messages using the `message_type` field. But I am having difficulty in specifying the field which is suitable to carry this out.

Is this DB design even adequate enough to perform this task? Should I resort to some other schema? I am using PostgreSQL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You could have a generic foreignkey and a model for each message type?

Answer (score 0):

There is no diffrence between `CharField` and `ImageField` for database, django save the path of file to databse and save itself to `upload_to` path when use `FileField`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, `ImageField` , `URLField`, and `CharField` ( or `TextField` ?) would suffice as far as storing the content in string format goes. I just wanted to know whether it's possible to store the data in a more 'interpretable' way for the Django ORM. But if there is no other way, then this is also fine.